# ASP: Constraints and triggers problem in visual studio

Tags: asp.net

I detached my database from sql server and dragged and dropped in into visual studio in the App_data folder. Created a new connection to this database, tested it, everything works fine.

The problem is I created a set of constraints and triggers back in sql server management studio. When I open the tables in visual studio, no constraints neither triggers appear. This problem is affecting my web application by not storing values neither perform custom defined formulas.

Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out for express features: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165636.aspx

Was the original instance a SQL Server Express server that you attached to?  This list does support triggers, but doesn't mention constraints.  Also, you have to use the query optimizer, so I think that means there is no direct option in SQL Server to see it, but you could work with it via the optimizer or scripting.

HTH.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008 R2

Comment: The full blown version of SQL?  If the full version, why are you hosting it in app_data, typically databases for express are in App_Data....

Comment: If I want to host the web application, how can i provide the connection string? shouldn't it be that the database is within the web app? rather than being outside?